# What metal is along the top of a plaster wall in a 1930s house?

Tags: plaster, lath-and-plaster

I have a house built in the 1930s with lath and plaster walls. I was planning to install a hook, so I needed to find a stud. My normal stud finder didn't work (as expected), so I used some rare earth magnets. However, I found that there is about 3-4 inches of something metal all along the top of the wall. This seems to extend to every wall on the floor. I am fairly new to this era house - what could be along the top of all the walls that would be made of metal?

[image: top of wall]

Comment: Likely a metal corner.

Comment: Would a metal corner run along all walls? What is the purpose of a metal corner?

Comment: does it extend to the ceiling?

Comment: google `metal lath plaster picture`

Comment: It goes from the ceiling down a few inches. If it was metal lath plaster mesh, I would think it would extend all the way down, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is likely to be "[drywall bead](https://www.google.com/search?q=drywall+bead) " used to make joins between plasterboard at internal an external corners. It makes it easier for builders or renovators to produce a clean sharp corner.

Comment: Looking at the dimensions of where the metal is (via magnet), this looks about right. Thanks!